# Cut off overlapping polygon areas at their cutting edge

Tags: qgis, intersection

I have a polygon layer with many circle polygons in it, which are overlapping each other.

I now would like to cut off the overlapping areas at their cutting edge:

[image]

[image]

I use QGIS 2.2 and couldn't find a tool to do it, all vector tools are only working if there are two different layers to cut (there is now way to convert it to different layers because I have over 100 polygons, which are overlapping each other different times.)

Comment: I don't know why, but this site always cuts my introducing "Hi" in this thread,even when i editet it, so now you get it this way afterwards: HI ;-)

Comment: I think we've had that question before but I can't find it right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform this using the [***v.clean***](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.clean.html) tool set provided by GRASS. Take a careful look at the *break* and *bpol* tools.  From QGis you can access this tool set either through [Sextante](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/sextante/) or the [GRASS plug-in](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/grass_integration/grass_integration.html).

Comment: First of all, thanks for your quick answer! I tried different v.clean tools at a test layer with two overlapping polygones (like in the example above), but there is no effect on the shapes!? Do you have any hint, what could be my error here?

Comment: I can't say. Can you make this layer available somehow, e.g. posting the GML at Pastebin?

Comment: I tried it again with one of my "real" layers, but without difference. I uploaded the gml (zipped with7Zip) here: http://www.file-upload.net/download-8805199/Test_Buffer.7z.html

Comment: Maybe its helpful to know what i have in mind with this. The circles are production areas of different places. When they share space, it should be splitted 50/50 to both of them. Thats why i want to cut them at the cutting edges like shown above.