# Expanding polygons and clipping at midpoint?

Tags: qgis, polygon, buffer, clip

I have several separate shapefiles with polygon features. The end goal is to maintain separate shapefiles for each polygon but form a contiguous, non-overlapping coverage for my area. Basically, I guess I am trying to fill in gaps using a consistent, repeatable process.

The polygons are irregular:
[image]

Initially I thought I could buffer each polygon and do something like this for the overlaps: [Cut off overlapping polygon areas at their cutting edge](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92288/cut-off-overlapping-polygon-areas-at-their-cutting-edge?rq=1) but was unable to perform using v.clean. Is there another way?  Most methods I see seem to favor one polygon over the other and I'm trying for a standard or middle distance.

If a buffer is not used, I want to expand each polygon in a standardized way and have them meet at a 'midpoint' between each polygon. Is this possible? Maybe something with node snapping tolerances? I am currently using QGIS 2.16 and don't have any experience using python.

Comment: If you only have to do a few of these, you could turn on snapping, create a new polygon that fills the gap and is snapped to the vertices of the neighboring polygons, split the new polygon roughly in half,
 (advanced digitizing toolbar: split features tool), copy-paste each half into the shapefile of its neighboring polygon, and merge it with that polygon.

Comment: Thank you; this may be what I end up doing because I don't have too many polygons right now. However, I think my next round will be more complex, so I'd love to have something less 'free-hand' with the split features.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure your polygons have a unique id.

1. [Extract vertices](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#extract-vertices)
2. Create [Voronoi polygons](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#voronoi-polygons)
3. [Aggregate](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#aggregate) voronoi polygons based on the unique id.

*Resulting polygons outlined in red:*
[image]