# Alternative ways of patching gaps in a polygon

Tags: qgis

I'm working in QGIS.

I have a shapefile with certain plots of land highlighted and I plan to calculate the distance of features to the borders of these plots. But the plots have the roads and rivers going through them as gaps in the polygons. Like this:

[image]

Of course, this messes with the distance calculation I want. The goal is to create new polygons that just the outline only. I have tried the hole function in QGIS. I also tried buffering with dissolving then reversing the buffer. What other methods might work to fill in the gaps?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filling holes in polygons automatically using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164296/filling-holes-in-polygons-automatically-using-qgis)

Comment: Unfortunately, that solution didn't work for my file/

Comment: Does this help? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/420622/88814

Comment: No, unfortunately. It's gaps within a polygon and not between them